# android automation using cucumber and python

Tags: android, python, cucumber, automated-tests, bdd

So I'm very new to software. I'm trying to figure out how to automate testing of an android .apk using Cucumber BDD and python for scripting? I'm a little familiar with intellij IDE so I'd like to use that. I was able to previously set up a test framework using cucumber-JVM and appium with the maven build tool, mostly because of the tutorials by G BoxT on youtube. I know this question is kind of vague but maybe someone could point me in the right direction as far as what tools I need to put this framework together? I've done a lot of reading but just can't seem to make sense of how it would all be put together. What dependencies would I need?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds a lot like you are wanting to use something similar to my configuration.  Though, I'm not really sure you would want to use IntelliJ when you can use Pycharm.

That said, with Pycharm, I have the Behave plugin [this is a good guide.](https://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2014/09/feature-spotlight-behavior-driven-development-in-pycharm/)
You have to have the professional version of Pycharm but I have been able to write Gherkin using any text editor and naming the BDD feature file with a .feature extension.  As long as the feature file is in the same directory as your scripts, it should be relatively straight forward.

My set up:

PyCharm Pro with the Behave plugin and the python bindings for appium.
Appium 1.6.3.
Android Studio or you can use real devices and only install the android SDK.

Thats it really.

As far as training is concerned, you might want to look at Udemy, but there are a fair amount of resources on YouTube, but I've learned a lot on Udemy.

Lotsa Luck!